# Converting Div To Dropdown Menu

Tags: jquery, html

I am having 2 `Div` Tag Set As Below

```
<div id="testing1" >
   <div id="newpar" >
      <div  id="1" > 1 </div>
      <div  id="2" > 2 </div>
      <div  id="3" > 3 </div>
      <div  id="4" > 4 </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="testing2" >
    <div id="newpar" >
      <div  id="1" > 1 </div>
      <div  id="2" > 2 </div>
      <div  id="3" > 3 </div>
      <div  id="4" > 4 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

I need to convert the `div` which has the `id`  `newpar`  as a `drop down menu` (Select Menu). is that possible...

Comment: you can do it with css too, jquery is just an option. for dropdown list but for a select menu with selected item shown u will definetly need jquery

Comment: hi i am very new to jquery kindly give me a demo please

Comment: While you _can_ do this with `div`, a more accurate representation of the structure would be to use `ul`/`li`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sel = $('<select id="tesing2"/>');
$('#testing2 div').each(function(){
    sel.append('<option value='+this.id+'>'+this.innerHTML+'</option>')
})  
$('#testing2').replaceWith(sel)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4y2wD/)

As IDs must be unique you can use classes instead:

```
<div id="testing2">
    <div class="newpar">
      <div  id="1"> 1 </div>
      <div  id="2"> 2 </div>
      <div  id="3"> 3 </div>
      <div  id="4"> 4 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var sel = $('<select id="tesing"/>');
$('#testing2 > div > div').each(function(){
    sel.append('<option class='+this.parentNode.className+'>'+this.innerHTML+'</option>')
})

$('#testing2 > div').replaceWith(sel)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DdC5C/4/

Comment: hi its working but i need to set the <option id as in the parrent div id how is this possible ...

Comment: @user1565383 this is possible, but makes your document invalid, IDs must be unique. http://jsfiddle.net/4y2wD/1/

Comment: any way the id will be dynimic not its not an issue kindly check my fiddle i have updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/varunms/DdC5C/1/

Comment: @user1565383 What is the logic behind these IDs? How they should be generated?

Comment: hi i need to set the option id as the div id which is in the div below  newpar

Comment: see this i have give an example that how i need http://jsfiddle.net/varunms/WXK7S/5/

Comment: @user1565383 sorry, you should post another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

Pure css answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Wycbd/1/

And just a couple points: id's cannot start with a number, and they have to be unique. In my fiddle, I changed the `id="1"` `id="2"` to `class="one"` `class="two"`

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy :)

```
$(function() {
    var id2convert = "testing2",
        divs = $("div", "#" + id2convert),
        select = $("<select id=\"" + id2convert + "\">");

    divs.each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        select.append("<option value=\"" + text + "\">" + text + "</option>");
    });

    divs.parent().replaceWith(select);
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rFLy5/1/)

Comment: hi its working but i need to set the <option id as in the parrent div id how is this possible ...